# Conditional left join in Oracle, single row per entity

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a list of my companies.

Every year, the company may be assigned to a category. So there is a set of categories for each year and the company may (or may not) have to be assigned to one of the categories for the given year.

In my list of companies, I want to add information about the company's category for the current year (let's say 2023). Or null, if there is no category for this year.

Here is my example schema to copy and paste:

```
-- Table COMPANY
CREATE TABLE COMPANY (
    ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 'Meta');
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID, NAME) VALUES (2, 'Alphabet');
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID, NAME) VALUES (3, 'Microsoft');

-- Table EVENT, containing information about the year
CREATE TABLE EVENT (
    ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    YEAR NUMBER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO EVENT (ID, YEAR) VALUES (1, 2021);
INSERT INTO EVENT (ID, YEAR) VALUES (2, 2022);
INSERT INTO EVENT (ID, YEAR) VALUES (3, 2023);

-- Table CATEGORY referencing the table EVENT
CREATE TABLE CATEGORY (
    ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    EVENT_ID NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT fk_event FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_ID) REFERENCES EVENT(ID)
);

-- Populating the table CATEGORY
INSERT INTO CATEGORY (ID, NAME, EVENT_ID) VALUES (1, 'A 21', 1);
INSERT INTO CATEGORY (ID, NAME, EVENT_ID) VALUES (2, 'A 22', 2);
INSERT INTO CATEGORY (ID, NAME, EVENT_ID) VALUES (3, 'A 23', 3);
INSERT INTO CATEGORY (ID, NAME, EVENT_ID) VALUES (4, 'B 21', 1);
INSERT INTO CATEGORY (ID, NAME, EVENT_ID) VALUES (5, 'B 22', 2);
INSERT INTO CATEGORY (ID, NAME, EVENT_ID) VALUES (6, 'B 23', 3);

-- Assigning companies to categories, MANY TO MANY relation
CREATE TABLE CMP_X_CAT (
    COMPANY_ID NUMBER,
    CATEGORY_ID NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT pk_cmp_x_cat PRIMARY KEY (COMPANY_ID, CATEGORY_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_cmp FOREIGN KEY (COMPANY_ID) REFERENCES COMPANY(ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_cat FOREIGN KEY (CATEGORY_ID) REFERENCES CATEGORY(ID)
);

INSERT INTO CMP_X_CAT (COMPANY_ID, CATEGORY_ID) VALUES (1, 1); -- Meta: A 21
INSERT INTO CMP_X_CAT (COMPANY_ID, CATEGORY_ID) VALUES (1, 2); -- Meta: A 22
INSERT INTO CMP_X_CAT (COMPANY_ID, CATEGORY_ID) VALUES (2, 5); -- Alphabet: B 22
INSERT INTO CMP_X_CAT (COMPANY_ID, CATEGORY_ID) VALUES (2, 6); -- Alphabet: B 23
```

In the result set, every company **should be present exactly once**.

I am struggling with the results:

- Sometimes, some company is missing
- Sometimes there is more than one row per company

See my attempts and results:

1. Outputs one row for each category. And also one row, if company does not have any category:

```
SELECT company.*, category.*, event.*
FROM company 
LEFT JOIN cmp_x_cat ON company.id = cmp_x_cat.company_id 
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = cmp_x_cat.category_id 
LEFT JOIN event ON category.event_id = event.id
ORDER BY company.id;
```

```
        ID NAME                         ID NAME                   EVENT_ID         ID       YEAR
---------- -------------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Meta                          1 A 21                          1          1       2021
         1 Meta                          2 A 22                          2          2       2022
         2 Alphabet                      5 B 22                          2          2       2022
         2 Alphabet                      6 B 23                          3          3       2023
         3 Microsoft
```

2. Using the join condition, prints the same as above, but event is only set when equal to 2023. This helps me identify companies, which do not have category for current year:

```
SELECT company.*, category.*, event.*
FROM company 
LEFT JOIN cmp_x_cat ON company.id = cmp_x_cat.company_id 
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = cmp_x_cat.category_id 
LEFT JOIN event ON category.event_id = event.id AND event.year = 2023 OR event.year IS NULL
ORDER BY company.id;
```

```
        ID NAME                         ID NAME                   EVENT_ID         ID       YEAR
---------- -------------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Meta                          2 A 22                          2                      
         1 Meta                          1 A 21                          1                      
         2 Alphabet                      5 B 22                          2                      
         2 Alphabet                      6 B 23                          3          3       2023
         3 Microsoft
```

3. INNER JOIN skips companies without any category (Microsoft):

```
SELECT company.*, category.*, event.*
FROM company 
LEFT JOIN cmp_x_cat ON company.id = cmp_x_cat.company_id 
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = cmp_x_cat.category_id 
INNER JOIN event ON category.event_id = event.id
ORDER BY company.id;
```

```
        ID NAME                         ID NAME                   EVENT_ID         ID       YEAR
---------- -------------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Meta                          1 A 21                          1          1       2021
         1 Meta                          2 A 22                          2          2       2022
         2 Alphabet                      5 B 22                          2          2       2022
         2 Alphabet                      6 B 23                          3          3       2023
```

4. Prints single row per company, which is what I want, but does not contain Meta. Because it is assigned to categories, but not from the year 2023:

```
SELECT company.*, category.*, event.*
FROM company 
LEFT JOIN cmp_x_cat ON company.id = cmp_x_cat.company_id 
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = cmp_x_cat.category_id 
LEFT JOIN event ON category.event_id = event.id
WHERE event.year = 2023 OR event.year IS NULL
ORDER BY company.id;
```

```
        ID NAME                         ID NAME                   EVENT_ID         ID       YEAR
---------- -------------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2 Alphabet                      6 B 23                          3          3       2023
         3 Microsoft
```

I was able to achieve something I want using nested SELECT, but I cannot use it because I am limited by my framework - I need to transform the SQL into Doctrine DQL, which does not support nested SELECTs in way I needed.

Maybe it is possible some GROUPing of rows? Maybe using UNION in some way?

***EDIT:***
Here is the possible expected result:

```
 ID NAME           ID  NAME     EVENT_ID         ID       YEAR
--- ------------- ---- ------ ---------- ---------- ----------
  1 Meta           ??? ???          null       null       null
  2 Alphabet         6 B 23            3          3       2023
  3 Microsoft     null null         null       null       null
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to follow because you have some many failed attempts that do not give the answer you want but nowhere do you obviously state what the expected answer would be for your sample data.

Comment: Thank you MT0, I posted also the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use brackets to specify the precedence of the joins:

```sql
SELECT  c.*, t.name, e.year
FROM    company c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          cmp_x_cat x
          INNER JOIN category t
          ON x.category_id = t.id
          INNER JOIN event e
          ON e.id = t.event_id AND e.year = 2023
        )
        ON (c.id = x.company_id)
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ID | NAME | NAME | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Alphabet | B 23 | 2023 |
| 3 | Microsoft | *null* | *null* |
| 1 | Meta | *null* | *null* |

If a company can have multiple categories in a single year and you want to display them as a comma-delimited list on a single line then aggregate using `LISTAGG`:

```sql
SELECT  c.id,
        MAX(c.name) AS name,
        LISTAGG(t.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.name) AS categories
FROM    company c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          cmp_x_cat x
          INNER JOIN category t
          ON x.category_id = t.id
          INNER JOIN event e
          ON e.id = t.event_id AND e.year = 2023
        )
        ON (c.id = x.company_id)
GROUP BY c.id
```

Which, for the sample data (that does not have any companies with multiple categories), outputs:

| ID | NAME | CATEGORIES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Meta | *null* |
| 2 | Alphabet | B 23 |
| 3 | Microsoft | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u2MGA67j)

Comment: Your example works just as expected. :-)

Company can have only single category per year, so the second example is not necessary.

Now I just need to rewrite the code into DQL. :-)

Comment: Your solution works in pure SQL, I was not able to rewrite it in DQL though. :-( Parenthesis in JOIN clause is not supported by DQL and I was not able to find any workaround. Thank you for your time anyway.